# Html2Canvas rendered picture showing borders/grid of table

Tags: javascript, c#, css, html2canvas

i am trying to export a div with html2canvas to pdf. Inside the div are 4 Tables.
The Problem is the output in the pdf, because the grid/borders of the table are visible in default black, but i set any border-colors to transparent. Surprisingly the random-lines hide when i zoom inside the generated pdf. 
Do you know how to prevent thees unwanted lines?

Picture below...

[image]

Backend-code where i add the picture to the pdf-document...

```
        base64 = hfImageData2.Value.Split(',')[1];
        bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        iTextSharp.text.Image img2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        img2.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
        img2.ScalePercent(2000);
        img2.ScaleToFit(790, 700);
        document.Add(img2);
```

html2canvas javascript where i save the div to hiddenfield...

```
        function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
            html2canvas($("#containerChart")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
                __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
            });
            return false;
        }
```

The div element...

```
         <div id="containerChart" runat="server"  style="margin-left: 2.5%; display: table;"></div>
```